# Using SharedPreferences to disable ads on in-app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, admob, sharedpreferences

I am trying to remove AdMob ads in my app upon an in-app purchase. I already have the code to hide and disable the ads working. I also have in-app billing implemented. I just need to find a way to keep the ads hidden and disabled if the user has made a purchase.

I have a boolean stored in `SharedPreferences`, which, upon a successful in-app purchase, should permanently remove the ads in the app. **This works,** but when the app is closed and reopened, the ads are back and you cannot perform the purchase again.

In `onCreate()` method:

```
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.wsandhu.conjugation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (adFree) {
        prefs.edit().putBoolean("adFree", true).commit();
    } else {
        adFree = prefs.getBoolean("adFree", false);
    }
```

In-App Billing implementation:

```
/* FOR IN-APP BILLING */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener  =
        new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    // Handle error
                    return;
                } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {

                    // Sets purchased boolean to true
                    adFree = true;

                    // Restart app
                    Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        };

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure
        } else {
            Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
            if (purchase != null) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
};

public void buyFullVersion() {
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "mypurchasetoken");
}
```

I don't really know what I'm doing wrong... I've uploaded the app to Google Play alpha testing more than ten times now and I'm getting a bit frustrated each time I wait two hours and it doesn't work. :P Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
adFree = true;
```

Causing issue when user opening app again after closing *`adFree` variable value getting reset to default*.

Do it as by updating status in `SharedPreferences` when purchase is successful :

```
  ...
 }else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
     //save value in SharedPreferences here
       prefs.edit().putBoolean("adFree", true).commit();
  }
```

and in `onCreate` method check for `adFree` as:

```
prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.wsandhu.conjugation",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

if(prefs.contains("adFree")){
  if(prefs.getBoolean("adFree", false)){
     // disable ads here
   }else{
      // enable ads here
    }
}else{
  // enable ads
}
```

Comment: Quick question before I test this out: why do you disable ads in the if-statement where you use `getBoolean("adFree", false)`? Shouldn't the boolean value be true?

Comment: @wasimsandhu: Yes,  when user start your app first time or purchase is not done then adFree value in preference will be false and `getBoolean("adFree", false)` return false instead of true

Comment: So the ads should actually be enabled in that block then, not disabled, right?

Comment: I want to show the ads when the user has NOT purchased the in-app purchase. The apps will be disabled when the user has purchased the in-app purchase.

Comment: @wasimsandhu: Yes, when once app purchased then ads will disabled and never show user

Comment: @wasimsandhu: Note: ads will enabled again when user reinstall your app so you are need to call google purchase check api to check item is already owned by user or not in your activity

Comment: Where should I call `getPurchase()`? In the `onCreate()` method?

Comment: @wasimsandhu: Yes and also use a flag and store it in SharedPreferences for getPurchase request if true to avoid call again-2 when user start app

Comment: Quick question: Why do you set adFree in sharedPreferences? Can be "hacked" easily on rooted phones. Isn't it better to check for the purchase again on app launch and if there's no successful purchase or there was an error, load the ads?